# Easiest way to change environment variables for bunch of servers?

Tags: ruby, ssh

What's the easiest way (in Ruby) to SSH remotely into a bunch of servers and change an environment variable in ~/.bash_profile ? Assuming, I have public key access to these servers and don't have to manually enter a password. Is there a way to do this with Capistrano?

Answer (score 0):

Using shell (not ruby, but you should be fine to update to ruby script)

```
while read -r server
do
ssh user@$server "sed -i s/old/new/ ~/.bash_profile"
done < server.list
```